# How does TFS's convertworkspaceitem work?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I'm trying to follow the instructions for deploying a database via TFS build listed here:
  http://www.mytechfinds.com/articles/software-testing/6-test-automation/64-db-deployment-tfs

The instructions include notes about how to configure a ConvertWorkspaceItem element. I've followed the directions, but TFS remains unhappy with my setting for 'Result' and 'Workspace'. For now, I simply entered the text from the directions ('dbproj' and 'Workspace', respectively). TFS complains about my values:

```
 Compiler error(s) encountered processing expression "dbproj". 'dbproj' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its production level.
```

I'm trying to find basic tutorial information on the ConvertWorkspaceItem element, but other than the MSDN reference page there isn't a lot of info. Does anyone know much about configuring this element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify valid variable names for both of these properties.  there should already be a variable declared in the workflow called workspace, You will need to declare a variable of type string that you wish to receive the result of this activity and specify it's name as the Result property.  It looks like in your linked article the author must have already created a variable called dbproj.  At the bottom of the workflow designer is a variables tab where you can define your own variables.

Comment: 1. What's the workflow element for declaring a variable? 2. The "workflow" variable gets autocapitalized, so I don't think that's going to fix it...

Comment: You declare workflow variables ni the variables tab of the workflow designer, it is not via dropping activities

Comment: Thanks; figured out how to add the variable. Next step is to figure out the correct setting for the "Workspace" setting. Any ideas?

Comment: Like I said, there should already be a variable in the workflow called workspace, you just pass that into the ConvertWorkspaceItem property.  You can examine the variables tab to confirm.

Comment: Aha! Turns out the Workspace variable was declared in a different scope. I moved it up to the global scope, so now every element can refer to it successfully.